# how to pass php array to jquery using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

help me to retrive the php array using ajax from one page to another

when ever user start input in that text field,at that time only it has to retrive the data from page2 using ajax

```
        <!doctype html> //page1
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <script>
          $(function() {
        var movies = <?php echo json_encode($varma); ?>; // here i want to pass that php array using ajax

            alert(JSON.stringify(movies));
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: movies
            });
          });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
          <input id="tags"> // input field
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>



        <?php //page 2
        $varma=array("ActionScript","AppleScript","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"); //php array
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Not sure this is your question but `autocomplete` can use ajax too.

Comment: @DigitalChris He's using that in his assignment `var movies = `

Answer (score 3):

The source attribute can have an URL as value. The URL must render json formated for the plugin.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: '/myMovies.php'
            });
```

/myMovies.php

```
<?php echo json_encode($varma); ?>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more generic method to ajax in php.

Construct the php array

```
$arReturn = array( 'name' => 'AliasM2K' );
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
print json_encode( $arReturn );
```

Perform ajax

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'ajaxPhp.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( oData ) {
        alert( oData.name );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

/*
   I read your problem and your code also and the suggestion from my side is :
    Some how you don't required any second page and doesn't required ajax for all this.
    You can autocomplete your textbox with PHP array's values using below successive code..
    Do yourself and enjoy.
 */
?>
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<?php
    $title_name = array();
    $fetch=array("ActionScript","AppleScript","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"); //php array
    foreach ($fetch as $data)
    {
        array_push($title_name,$data);  } ?>
<script>
    $(function(){ 
                var availableTags =<?php echo json_encode($title_name)?>;
                //PUT TEXTBOX ID here 
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({   source: availableTags }); 
            }); 
</script>        
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags"> // input field
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```